# SSH Config Option for arguments

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a ssh command that looks like this:

```
ssh -t user@hostname.com “argument”
```

I am trying to make this into a config file which is my .ssh/config
So far I have

```
Host somename
   HostName hostname
   User user
   RequestTTY force
```

I scoured the documentation but did not find an option to add the argument. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `RemoteCommand`.

```
Host somename
   HostName hostname
   User user
   RequestTTY force
   RemoteCommand argument
```